# 301 redirect urls with a slash in querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We built a new webshop for one of our clients, and are 301 redirecting their old url's to our normal ones. As usual we do this using .htaccess as follows:

`Redirect 301 /url1/ http://www.url2.com/` and it works fine.

BUT the old shop has this querystring ***with slashes in it (!)*** , for example:

`/epages/14353.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/61922345/Products/32428`

And as soon as I use this in a htaccess 301 redirect string it stops working. I don't get a 500 error or something like that, but when I visit `/epages/14353.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/61922345/Products/32428` it won't redirect. If I would use it with a querystring like the following (`/epages/14353.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=foobar`) I can visit it and get redirected, but not if there's a slash in it.

I tried backslashing it, encoding etc. but without the right results. Does any1 have an idea? I tried `AllowEncodedSlashes On` but it gave me a 500 error.

Comment: The `Redirect` directive doesn't match the query string at all. Are you sure you don't have something else that's causing this problem?

Comment: @HansWassink Can you show your full .htaccess in question?

Comment: @JonLin What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @anubhava `Redirect 301 /epages/14353.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/61922345/Products/32428 https://www.nu.nl` This is the only thing in the file. The old shop is gone, it's just a htaccess file, with one rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot match `QUERY_STRING` in `Redirect` directive, you need to use `mod_rewrite` based rule.

Have this one in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ObjectPath=/Shops/61922345/Products/32428
RewriteRule ^/?epages/14353\.sf/de_DE/?$ https://www.nu.nl? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid old cached data.

Comment: I wrote almost the same rewrite code, but unfortunately I'm still getting a 404 error that states `/epages/14353.sf/de_DE/` is not found. It's driving me crazy...

Comment: Maybe it's their server, I'll contact the host. Thanks @anubhava

Comment: I did that, it's enabled... `gibblygoo` returns 500.

Comment: `http://medidar-shop.de/epages/14353.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/61922345/Products/32428`

Comment: Nope, in the `/` directory, there is no `/epages/` folder

Comment: ok and is this the only rule you have in .htaccess or you have something else also?

Comment: Hmm same rules works fine on my Apache. For testing can your comment out `RewriteCond` line and retest.

Comment: I did, and it still doesnt work. It's probably something their host should fix, maybe they have a dark lurker somewhere. Thanks for all your help!